# Facing Bad Gateway for Google Analytics API

Tags: google-api, google-analytics-api

Frequently facing **Bad Gateway** exception when calling [Reporting API v4](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/rest/v4/reports/batchGet) of Google Analytics.

Read from Google that Bad Gateway exception occurs when *"The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server."*

The error we are facing is not persistent and occurs randomly. Is there any way to resolve this?

Comment: please edit your question and include your code.